# How does Internet Download Manager's Chrome extension work?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i see IDM create chrome extension to catch file from browser .
i open it , and it is so short code written on extension

in backhground.html

```
<html>
<body>
<embed id="__IDM__" type="application/x-idm-downloader" width="0" height="0"/>
<script src="background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and in background.js

```
var plugin = document.getElementById('__IDM__');
if (plugin)
{
    plugin.Initialize();

    chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(plugin.onBeforeRequest, { urls: ['<all_urls>'], types: ['main_frame','sub_frame','object','image'] }, ['blocking']);
    chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(plugin.onHeadersReceived, { urls: ['<all_urls>'], types: ['image'] }, ['responseHeaders']);
}

function injectContentScript(tabs)
{
    var details = { file: 'contentscript.js', allFrames: true };

    for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++)
        try { chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[i].id, details); }
    catch (exc) { }
}

chrome.tabs.query({ url: 'http://*/*'  }, injectContentScript);
chrome.tabs.query({ url: 'https://*/*' }, injectContentScript);
```

it's send all url to embed file !
i dont understand how this embed work , and how can i create like this embed code to catch data from browser to know how it work

i remember yahoo messenger have some thing like code that when user click in browser yahoo chat box opened and this code created on win registry . i think this will be like that but how !?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html